# How to call a server side function from client side (e.g. html button onclick) in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I need a complete basic example in Node.js of calling a server-side function from (client side) html button onclick event, just like in ASP.NET and C#.

I am new to Node.js and using the Express framework.

Any help?

IMPROVED QUESTION:

//server side :

```
var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var user = require('./routes/user');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();

// all environments

app.set('views',__dirname + '/views');
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.set('view engine', 'html');

app.use(app.router);

app.get("/",function(req,res)
{
  res.render('home.html');
});


// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

//Client Side

```
 <input type="button" onclick="" />  <--just want to call the serverside function from here-->
```

Comment: You need to communicate with the server over HTTP, using AJAX or a form POST or websockets.

Comment: I have googled alot, but unable to get the correct example,

Comment: @SaadAbdullah: What don't you understand? Node.js is a much thinner web platform; you need to understand the underlying technologies (HTML and HTTP).

Comment: @SLaks: thanx for your response sir, I am making replica of wikipedia for my web-programming semester project, (means, I am a noob with node.js) I am stuck at some point, I just want to know that how can i use the server side function from client side event?

Comment: @SaadAbdullah: You can't call a function on one computer from another computer.  You need to send a request over the network.

Comment: As I said earlier, you _need_ to understand the underlying protocols.  You can try to use higher socket abstractions, but you will fail horribly if you don't understand what's going on.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Here's an example using Express and a HTML form.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(app);

app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.post('/', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.send(200);
});

server.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP);
```

The code above will start an instance of Express, which is a web application framework for Node. The `bodyParser()` module is used for parsing the request body, so you can read post data. It will then listen for `POST` requests on the route `/`.

```
<form method="post" action="/">
  <input type="test" name="field1">
  <input type="test" name="field2">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

And if you submit that form, in `req.body` for the route `/`, you will get the result:

```
{ field1: 'form contents', field2: 'second field contents' }
```

To run a function, just put it inside the `POST` handler like this:

```
var foo = function() {
  // do something
};

app.post('/', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.send(200);

  // sending a response does not pause the function
  foo();
});
```

If you don't want to use Express then you can use the native HTTP module, but you'd have to parse the HTTP request body yourself.

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  if (request.method === 'POST') {
    var data = '';

    request.on('data', function(chunk) {
      data += chunk;
    });

    request.on('end', function() {
      // parse the data
      foo();
    });
  }
}).listen(80);
```

Comment: where is app.get function?

Comment: This is an example, not a full solution. You can find out how to use it in the documentation: http://expressjs.com

Comment: I have checked the API, I cannot find any example regarding calling server side function.

but thanx for your answer :)

Comment: `app.use(bodyParser());` //Now deprecated
You now need to call the methods separately
`app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());`
`app.use(bodyParser.json());` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24330014/bodyparser-is-deprecated-express-4

Comment: There was no example showing how a script is named in an onClick statement that is served by Express.