# How to pass a function to express-handlebars in nodejs-express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, express, express-handlebars

I am trying to pass a function in express-handlebar,
 but it is not working.
I am using app.js as server file and index.handlebars as handlebar file.

app.js

```
const express=require('express');
const app=express();
const csc=require('countrycitystatejson');
const exphbs=require('express-handlebars');
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs());
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

// console.log(csc.getAll());

function hello(){
  console.log('hello');
}

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index',{
      hello:hello
    });
});

 app.listen(3000);
```

index.handlebars

```
<button onclick="hello()">click</button>
```

Comment: function hello is on the server side, your button is calling a function on the client side. Move function hello on the client side and provide whatever variables you need from the server.

Comment: Thanks @Jabberwocky but how to move it to client side ?

Comment: This may help [html button onclick in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18831783/how-to-call-a-server-side-function-from-client-side-e-g-html-button-onclick-i)

Answer (score 0):

Best to create a helper for this. Below an example and referring to [Github](https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars) for more info on the topic.

```
const express=require('express');
const app=express();
const csc=require('countrycitystatejson');
const exphbs=require('express-handlebars');

var hbs = exphbs.create({
    helpers: {
        hello: function () { console.log('hello'); }
    }
});

app.engine('handlebars', hbs.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

// console.log(csc.getAll());

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index');
});


app.listen(3000);
```

index.handlebars

```
<button onclick="{{hello}}">click</button>
```

Comment: By this approach, I will have to register every passing function as a helper function.
I don't think using this approach is good for big projects

Comment: Hi, 

The above answer is correct according to their documentation:
https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars